# Netty 4 and android 26

Tags: netty

The log line "Testing" is never printed. Can anyone see why? "connecting" is the last line to be printed.

This is done on Android 8 (26) and Netty 4.1.18.Final

I have this code:

```
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Log.d(RegisterAttemptTcp.class.getName(), "connecting");
        InetSocketAddress ria = new InetSocketAddress(toHostname, portDestination);
        b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.IP_TOS, 24)
                .remoteAddress(ria).handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new SimpleHandlerTest());
                    }
                });
        b.localAddress(portAttempt);

         ChannelFuture future = b.connect().sync();
        future.channel().closeFuture().await(8_000);
```

and:

```
public class SimpleHandlerTest extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelActive(ctx);
        Log.d(SimpleHandlerTest.class.getName(), "Testing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your connection attempt not completes (for whatever reason). By default netty should fail the `Future` of the connect operation after 10 seconds with a timeout exception.

Comment: Thanks Norm. The windows firewall did not report of blocked traffic so I assumed it wasn't blocking. Despite this I added a line with the port in question and it now works.